# How to use init_connect in azure database server for mysql

Tags: mysql, azure, azureportal, azure-mysql-database

Have created a mysql server which has somehow `log_bin` set to `ON` and `enforce_gtid_consistency` is also set to `ON`. Now this is causing few issues in my case and i want to turn `OFF` those variables.
Process i have tried

```
1. Create a .my.cnf file in user root (~/.my.cnf) and added
[mysqld]
enforce_gtid_consistency=OFF
```

> Result: No changes. It doesnt take effect.

```
2. In azure portal in init_connect variable i have set "SET enforce_gtid_consistency=OFF;" (because there is no mention of this variable in server parameters).
```

> Result: Cant connect to mysql after setting up value in this parameter.

Is there any way we can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

May be the following doc is helpful:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-read-replicas#global-transaction-identifier-gtid

Once GTID is enabled, you cannot turn it back off. If you need to turn GTID OFF, please contact support.